# Pop an item if its value is false

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mutiple select from Angular Material. I am able to get the item's value and checked value(true/false). I need to create an array, push if that item is true and pop if that item is false.

I have tried getting the boolean value:

html :

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-select multiple placeholder="Select Shows">
          <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="change($event)" *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
                    {{ food.viewValue }}
          </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

.ts :

```
 change(event)
  {
    if(event.isUserInput) {
      console.log(event.source.value, event.source.selected);
      this.ShowArray.push(event.source.value)
    }
  }
```

Expected Output :

```
["value1","value2","value3"]; //Inserted at first
["value1","value3"]; //Since the value2 is checked again, so it becomes false.
```

Comment: Is `event.source.selected` boolean?

Comment: Yes. It is boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st change event binding from option to `mat-select` like:

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-select multiple placeholder="Select Shows" (selectionChange)="change($event)">
          <mat-option  *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
                    {{ food.viewValue }}
          </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now change your change method like this:

```
change(event)
{
      console.log(event.source.value, event.source.selected);
      this.ShowArray = event.source.value;
}
```

Every time a selection is changed it will send an `array` of items so you can directly use that array without need of any extra logic.

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gl65wf)

Comment: @KedarKulkarni you're welcome, if this solved your problem you can consider marking this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever new input comes , check it with

```
 change(event)
      { 
         flag = 0
        if(event.isUserInput) {

          console.log(event.source.value, event.source.selected);
           if(event.source.selected){
               if(!this.ShowArray.includes(event.source.value)){
                this.ShowArray.push(event.source.value)     
           }
           }else{
              this.ShowArray.splice(this.ShowArray.indexOf(eventevent.source.value) , 1);
           }


        }
      }
```

Comment: Output of this : ["value1","value2","value3"] // Selected from dropdow. Afer selecting value2 again, it should pop from the array,but it still remains there. o/p: ["value1","value2","value3"]

Comment: @Pushprajsinh Ediding your answer by copying from another isn't a good practice :)

Comment: @AdritaSharma , Maybe our syntax are different :) and also way .

Comment: The idea is same.

Comment: There are 6 billion peoples in the world , anyone can have any idea . its co-incident that our idea is same . madam :) @AdritaSharma

Comment: MatSelect automatically sends a list of currently selected items on change event so why we need to add extra logic in detecting what changed? we can just simply assign the newly sent array to our array thats it?

Comment: @KedarKulkarni yes please check my detailed answer on this question